# How to open individual jquery dialogs

Tags: jquery, dialog, leaflet

I have multiple jquery ui dialogs being dynamically generated on a page, How do I target and  open individuals?

There needs to be 2 ways to open the dialog, a marker (playing around with leaflet maps) and a set of sidebar items that correspond to the markers on the map. Clicking on the marker opens the correct dialog but clicking on individual sidebar items opens all of the dialogs...

I have code:

```
$(function() {

var projectDialog = $('<div id="' + L.Util.stamp(e.layer) +'" class="model-wrap">\
    ' + pDesc + '\
    </div>');


     projectDialog.dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: pName,
            show: 'fade',
            hide: 'fade',
            dialogClass: (e.layer)

        });


$(e.layer).click(function() {

    projectDialog.dialog('open');

});


        // this is the sidebar link items - each item is given an id & href matching the corresponding e.layer
    $('.item').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        projectDialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `projectDialog.dialog('open');`, why don't you open the dialog by id?

`$('#' + *yourId*).dialog('open');`
or
`$('div[id=' + *yourId* + ']').dialog('open');`
You should be able to get the Id in your (e) in the click event since you said that it is given the id and href.

Also, you should probably be using .live() or .on() if you are trying to bind an event to a dynamically generated element.